# Prove $\lim \lbrack 5/n\rbrack=0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, let $\lbrack x\rbrack$ denote the greatest integer $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $b\leq x$. I would like to solve the following problem.

> Define a sequence $a_n=\lbrack 5/n\rbrack$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Using the definition of convergence, prove that $\lim a_n=0$.

**My Attempt**: To show that $\lim a_n=0$ is to show that $|\lbrack 5/n\rbrack|<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$. Observe that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $|\lbrack 5/n\rbrack|\leq 5/n <6/n$. Then, we can choose $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n_0>6/\epsilon$ by Archimedean property. For any $n\geq n_0$, we have $$n>6/\epsilon\implies 6/n<\epsilon\implies |\lbrack 5/n\rbrack|<\epsilon$$
which completes the proof.

It seems right, but I'm not sure if each of these steps are "allowed". Would appreciate if someone could confirm/correct my proof.

Comment: Well $a_n=0$ for all $n>5$ so for any $\epsilon>0$ $N=6$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making it more complicated than it needs to be (as is Fred in the other answer). What are the elements of the sequence for $n>5$? Now use the definition of convergence on that instead.

Comment: That is true, but I'm not sure if that directly uses the definition of convergence that the problem asks for.

Comment: Saying "for $n>5$, the sequence is equal to ... and therefore converges to $0$" doesn't use the definition. Saying "for any $\epsilon>0$, set $N=6$. Then $|a_n|=\cdots<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$." does use the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. But why $5/n<6/n$ ?

We have $n>5/\epsilon\implies 5/n<\epsilon\implies |\lbrack 5/n\rbrack|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Oh right, I somehow thought that the "$\geq$" between $|\lbrack 5/n\rbrack |$ and $5/n$ would interfere but I see that was wrong.